# Project-independent directories settings in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ 2012 Express project on Git that uses an external libcurl (not included in the repository).

I added the library by adding the corresponding paths on my machine (D:\libcurl\XXX) to `Include Directories` and `Library Directories` in **VC++ Directories** of **Project Properties**. So these settings are saved in the `.vcxproj` file.

If someone whose libcurl path is different from mine wants to build the project, he would have to:

- Change **VC++ Directories** settings in **Project Properties**.
  (then the project file will become modified, which is not what I want.)
- Move his libcurl files to match mine (D:\libcurl).
  (library path is forced to be D:\libcurl, not so flexible)

My question is: Is there a way to avoid this?

*(In old versions of Visual C++, I can set the paths in the global **VC++ Directories** of the `Tools->Options` dialog instead. But the feature is deprecated in recent versions.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe u can achieve this by using environment variables.
For example, you can add an environment variable called: LIBCURL
You can then set the LIBCURL to any path u want: D:\libcurl or X:\lib2.3b ...

no matter what ur library path is, u can always use the same VC++ Directories: $(LIBCURL)\XXX